# How to find number of entries grouped by something and retrieve only those above average?

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery

I have two tables: Profile and Record. In Profile, I have student names and other information, whereas, in Record, I have rows with curriculum information. In the Record table, a single student can have many rows. I need to calculate the number of rows grouped by student_name, but only retrieve those student names with more rows than the average (number of rows/total number of students). I can find the number of rows grouped by student_name, but I can't write a subquery to display only those above average. Could someone please explain a method to me?

This is what I have for now:

```
SELECT student_name, COUNT(*)
  FROM Profile p 
  JOIN Record r
    ON p._id = r._id
 GROUP BY student_name
```

The desired output is only to retrieve students_name with the above avg no. of rows in the Records table:

| student_name | No. of Records |
| --- | --- |
| Ali | 556 |
| John | 244 |

Comment: Please provide sample tables with desired output

Comment: I have added the desired output. For the table sample table, I think it's not necessary because the no of records = the number of rows representing the student in the Record table.

Comment: I've tried answering. Check and accept if it solves your problem. Else add your comment so that I can make req changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you can use `sub-query` to get your desired output.

**Code:**

```
SELECT student, COUNT(*) AS no_of_records  
FROM record
GROUP BY student
HAVING no_of_records > (SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT student) FROM record);
```

**Explanation:**

- The `sub-query` here will return average row count from record table
- In the `outer-query`, we are calculating number of rows for each student and comparing it with sub-query's result

Note: You can join it with profile table in outer query if needed.

Look at the *[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=86f91e48bd8ab11d2c514b2ead7e0a3c)* to understand it better